# Pdf book reader in php?

Tags: php, pdf

Actually I have to upload pdf files and need to read on my website as book reader like a presentation. Please show me the possible ways to achieve my goals.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to read the content out from the pdf files and read them using some purpose built reader? Or do you just want to upload the files to your site and let people read using any plain old PDF reader in the browser or download a copy?

Comment: No its not about downloading the pdf file?? It must look like sliding pages like presentations. I dont have much idea about pdf files in php. How i could make it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/). You simply upload your document to their website and embed their reader on your website. This is the easiest way, and you get things like searchability. Their reader also works like Adobe's Acrobat Reader.

The downside is that you are uploading your documents onto a public website, so everyone will be able to view it. Perhaps they might have settings where you can lock your documents so that only certain people can see them.

The next solution is to roll your own. You can use [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/#home). In this case, you will need to find a way to convert your PDF files to HTML files or perhaps image files. With images, your text won't be selectable, and they won't be discoverable by search engines. Again, converting PDF to HTML can also be difficult as you might lose formatting in the process.

But it is entirely up to your use case. Personally, I would go with scribd, as their platform works very well, and you won't have to worry about implementing your own system.

Comment: no i cant use scribd because i have to upload the pdf file and view it as presentation so i cant use any other conversion tools :(

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/), I use [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert the pdf to swf as I used the flash version but there is a javascript version too.

Comment: i think u dont get my question .. i just have to upload pdf files and view it as presentation . I cant use any software to convert. Any ways thanks for ur concern